# How to convert a JPG image to a string in java/android

Tags: java, android

I have read many many posts regarding this. I am trying to upload a picture to the server. It should be an encoded string of a JPG image. I have tried to do it the other way by using multipart form but that didn't work for me. Any idea?

Comment: Check out Base64 encoding

Comment: Ascii85! 25% vs 33% bigger than input.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with

```
String encodedFile = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this -

```
    ImageView image =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

    //encode image to base64 string
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String imageString = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

    //decode base64 string to image
    imageBytes = Base64.decode(imageString, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap decodedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
    image.setImageBitmap(decodedImage);
```